# Magento 2.2.0 - __construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory,

Tags: magento2, module, controllers

**Controller File**

```
<?php

namespace Magento2\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;


class Index extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

It throws below exception while trying to run controller, while I have already mentioned `use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;`

**Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento2\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory**

If I simply use below, it works

```
<?php

namespace Magento2\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;


class Index extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

How can I resolve the `__construct()` error ?

Comment: did you get the solution??? actually I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

**Change __construct function to**

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {

    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    );
}
```

**and Change**

> class Index extends  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

**from**

> class Index extends Action

Also remove

> use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

Comment: How come swapping two lines work - ` $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    ); ?`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct there is no any issue.

Follow below step

1) remove cache: `php bin/magento cache:flush`

2) remove var/generation : `rm -rf var/generation`

Comment: It did not worked.

Comment: Still there is error?

Comment: No, error is resolved by swapping these two lines in construct function - `$this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    );`. Although I tried clearing cache and var/generation, but it did not helped.